# Using "$" in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I see { } are used for closures, and then I believe when a $ is put in front of braces, it is simply doing a variable substitution within a string.  I can't find the documentation on how the $ works in the reference ... hard to search on it unfortunately, and the Groovy String documentation is lacking in introducing this.  Can you please point me to the documentation and/or explain the "$" operator in Groovy -- how all it can be used?   Does Grails extend it at all beyond Groovy?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In a GString (groovy string), any valid Groovy expression can be enclosed in the ${...} including method calls etc.

This is detailed in the [following page](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that it's in the GString section.  The String section used ${} in one of its examples and didn't introduce it.

Comment: I never knew one could do so much in a GString.

Comment: One precaution that some of us may miss, do use double quotes to make it work i.e 'Hello ${varSam}' will not work but "Hello ${varSam}"

Answer (score 52):

Grails does not extend the usage of $ beyond Groovy. Here are two practical usages of $

### String Interpolation

Within a GString you can use $ without {} to evaluate a property path, e.g.

```
def date = new Date()
println "The time is $date.time"
```

If you want to evaluate an expression which is more complex than a property path, you must use ${}, e.g.

```
println "The time is ${new Date().getTime()}"
```

### Dynamic Code Execution

Dynamically accessing a property

```
def prop = "time"
new Date()."$prop"
```

Dynamically invoking a method

```
def prop = "toString"
new Date()."$prop"()
```

As pointed out in the comments this is really just a special case of string interpolation, because the following is also valid

```
new Date().'toString'()
```

Comment: Isn't your 2nd usage just an example of the 1st?  As you can call methods by their string name like `new Date().'toString'()`? So it's just the first usage case to build a String which is then used to access methods/properties?

Comment: @tim - you're right, I guess what I'm really showing are two practical usages of string interpolation rather than two usages of $. I'll try and make this clearer

Comment: +1 from me :-)  Sorry I was being slightly pedantic, as it's a good example of where `$` is really useful

Comment: Cool - thanks for showing an example of dynamically accessing a property and dynamically invoking method

Comment: I'd like to mark yours as an answer as well, or raise the points, but it is not allowing me to.  Thanks for the grails clarification and examples.

Comment: if the string containing $variable, arrives from a select on the database, can it work?

Answer (score 11):

`$` is not an operator in Groovy.  In string substitution it identifies variables within the string - there's no magic there.  It's a common format used for inline variables in many template and programming languages.

All special Groovy operators are listed here: http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

**Work in side Jenkins File in pipeline** [image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
node{
          stage ('print'){
             def DestPath="D\$\\"
             println("DestPath:${DestPath}")
          }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Jenkins complains about the "def".