# Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plugin Inject Build Variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-scriptler

I would like to pre-populate Jenkins Parameter with a Build Variable using the [Dynamic Parameter Plug-In](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in).

I added a Groovy script under the *Scriptler* section of Jenkins:

```
return $JOB_NAME
```

JOB_NAME is Jenkins Environment Variable obtained from: ~/env-vars.html

And then added a "Dynamic Parameter (Scriptler)" as below:

[image]

However when clicking "Build with Parameters" I don't see the value populated.

I'm totally new to this and not sure if this is the right way to achieve it.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return "\$JOB_NAME"
```

NOTE: It's not sufficient to merely return the string `"$JOB_NAME"`, because Groovy [interpolates strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920826/question-about-in-groovy). It seems the script runs in an environment where specific build parameters are not available. By escaping the dollar sign, the string gets passed 1:1 to the dynamic parameter.

If you just want to inject the build- and/or job specific parameters, a text parameter defaulting to `$JOB_NAME` seems to work also.

Comment: Escaping "$" didn't work. Also tried defaulting to $JOB_NAME. But it just prints $JOB_NAME and not value.

Comment: @user1349736: `Job Name` - if this is the parameter's name, perhaps there's a problem with it having a space. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468397/how-can-you-access-an-environment-variable-that-has-a-space-in-its-name-in-bash).